# How to wait until a term is asserted in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I would like one of my prolog program to run in thread 2. When I assert something in the main thread, the program in thread 2 will monitor the assertion and execute different things accordingly. How can I do this?

I write something like this but it is really bad since it take a lot of cpu!

```
read_action(Act) :-
    open('action.txt', read, Stream),
    (can(go_next) ->
        read_line_to_codes(Stream, Act),
        write(Act),
        close(Stream)
        ;
        close(Stream),
        read_action(Act)),
    retractall(can(_)).
```

I am using Swipl

Comment: Threading model is implementation defined. You should state the Prolog you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [page](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%283,%278.3.1%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/threadcom.html%27%29%29) about thread communication it's explicit about the primitive to use: message queues.

thread_get_message locks waiting for a (possibly) specific term.